# Instance of Singleton null

Tags: java, android, singleton

I use some singletons in my Android app. From my `GlobalApp` (`extends Application`) class in `onCreate()` they are initialized like this:

```
public class GlobalApp extends Application{


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()); 
    MySingleton.init(databaseHelper); 

    }
}
```

And the singleton:

```
public class MySingleton{

   static MySingleton instance; 
   DatabaseHelper databaseHelper; 

   public static void init(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper){
      instance = new MySingleton(databaseHelper);
   }

}
```

I receive crashes for my app which clearly show that instance is `null` sometimes while my app runs. Most weird thing: those crashes only happen on the Samsung Galaxy S5!

My understanding was that

1. the `onCreate()` method of my `application` class was guaranteed to be called when my app is started
2. the instance on a Singleton could never become null, except for when the app would be completely restarted (in which case it should by recreated by my `application` class).

What's going on here?

PS: I know that Singletons are kinda frowned upon and extending the `application` class is also not recommended by everyone, but that's not the point here.

**EDIT:** Just for clarification, the code works 99% of the time. The question is not asking on how to implement the singleton pattern but rather how the lifecycle of my (or any) app can lead to the `instance` of a Singleton becoming `null` when it is created in the `application`'s `onCreate()`.

Comment: You need to give reference for `databaseHelper` in init method. Like `this.databaseHelper = databaseHelper;`

Comment: Can you please post the actual code? Because the above attempts to access a non-static field (`instance`) in static context (`init`) which is a compile-time-error.

Comment: you want instance of Application? CustomApp.getInstance() like this???

Comment: @NullByte Have you actually read the question?

Comment: Just a thought....As you know, onCreate can be called multiple times so try to save state information in onSaveInstanceState and restore it from the state bundle you get in on create.

Comment: oh question has been updated.. sorry didn't see that.

Comment: @Ascorbin Were you able to find out why it happens? I'm also facing a similar issue with my static object which is supposed to last the lifetime of the running app but is null sometimes on some screens. I have never encountered it but have seen crash reports from my users.

Comment: @droidster Nope, havent worked on this since then, never really found out. Sorry :(

Comment: @Ascorbin Oh! Thanks for replying and so quickly. I'm stuck and I'm trying to find a solution. Maybe saving the serialised data in prefs as a backup could be a way to avoid null pointers. Can't find/think of any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using singleton method in my application like my way,This works fine for me

```
        public class AddEventModel {

            private String event_name;
            private String event_image;
            private static AddEventModel _instance;

        //For Single Ton

        public static AddEventModel get_instance() {
                return _instance;
            }

            public static AddEventModel getInstance() {
                if (_instance == null) {
                    _instance = new AddEventModel();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
         public static void set_instance(AddEventModel _instance) {
                AddEventModel._instance = _instance;
            }

        //Getter setter for model.
            public String getEvent_image() {
                return event_image;
            }

            public void setEvent_image(String event_image) {
                this.event_image = event_image;
            }

            public String getEvent_name() {
                return event_name;
            }

            public void setEvent_name(String event_name) {
                this.event_name = event_name;
            }
```

**To set value in singleton I am doing like below,**

```
        edtEventName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //Save edit text value in single ton instance.  
                AddEventModel.getInstance().setEvent_name(edtEventName.getText().toString().trim());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
```

**To Get value back from singleton,**

```
     @Override
            public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();

        // Set same value saved in single ton before in onResume. 
        edtEventName.setText(AddEventModel.getInstance().getEvent_name());

        }
```

**Try to use singleton like this way,Hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code fro your singlton calass..

```
public class SingletonModel {
 private static SingletonModel instance;
 public DatabaseHelper databaseHelper; 


 public synchronized  static SingletonModel getSingletonModel() {

     if (instance == null) {
         instance = new SingletonModel();
     }
     return instance;

 }

 private void SingletonModel(){}

 }
```

Comment: I need a DatabaseHelper which needs a Context to be created so if I lazy-initialize the instance in getInstance I would need to pass the DatabaseHelper or a Context in every getInstance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you manifest file inside application have you put android:name="" like:

```
<application
        android:name=".application.DoodhwaalaApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have a constructor that accepts DatabaseHelper objects also make instance as static...

```
public class MySingleton {

    static MySingleton instance;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public/private MySingleton(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void init(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
        instance = new MySingleton(databaseHelper);
    }
}
```

Comment: The posted class was abbreviated for clarity. The constructor taking the Databasehelper as an argument exists of course.

Answer (score -1):

A singleton should have a private constructor
Hence the only fact you can do this

```
 instance = new MySingleton(databaseHelper);
```

in different class than MySingleton makes it something different from a Singleton

you should get the only existing instance through a public static method like

```
 instance = MySingleton.getInstance(databaseHelper);
```

If you need it, in its implementation be careful to verify there are not possibilities to return null

Answer (score -1):

Another way of creating Singleton class is by declaring private constructor along with class instance as static-final which will create your singleton object at the time of class loading. But make sure your DatabaseHelper object is initialized before MySingleton class is loading into JVM.

Refer below example for more details.

```
public class MySingleton {

    public static final MySingleton singleton = new MySingleton(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper);
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper=  null;

    private MySingleton(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
        this.databaseHelper = databaseHelper;
    }

    public MySingleton getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be stuck in multithreading issue: in one thread you set up singleton without volatile modifier (or synchronized section), and then in another thread you see stale value.

Comment: It is quite clear from the question it is not a multi threading issue...